# Dropdown list items didn't update immediately after change selection in another dropdown

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to update the values in Dropdown2 according to the selection of Dropdown1:

```
if A select in Dropdown1, "A1, A2" should show in Dropdown2, else "B1, B2" should show
```

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("GUI")
        self.root.geometry("300x300")

        self.frm = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frm.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        ttk.Label(self.frm, text="Dropdown1:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.drpDwn1 = ttk.Combobox(self.frm, values=["A", "B"], postcommand=self.reset_flavor)
        self.drpDwn1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

        ttk.Label(self.frm, text="Dropdown2:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.drpDwn2 = ttk.Combobox(self.frm, values=[""])
        self.drpDwn2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.root.mainloop()

    def reset_flavor(self):
        value = ["A1", "A2"] if self.drpDwn1.get() == "A" else ["B1", "B2"]
        self.drpDwn2.configure(values=value)
        self.drpDwn2.set("")


Gui()
```

But after I select A in Dropdown1, Dropdown2 values are "B1, B2", unless I select A again in Dropdown1.

---

I get an answer from GitHub Copilot:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

dropdown1 = ttk.Combobox(root, width=27, state="readonly")
dropdown1['values'] = ("A", "B")
dropdown1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
dropdown2 = ttk.Combobox(root, width=27, state="readonly")
dropdown2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

def dropdown1_event(event):
    if dropdown1.get() == "A":
        dropdown2['values'] = ("A1", "A2")
    elif dropdown1.get() == "B":
        dropdown2['values'] = ("B1", "B2")

dropdown1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", dropdown1_event)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is working.
But why the previous code with postcommand cannot work properly?

Comment: Does this help? value = ["B1", "B2"] if self.drpDwn1.get() == "A" else ["A1", "A2"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working as you expect because it is not the purpose of postcommand ([see here](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu/issues/193)):

> ttk.Combobox postcommand is used to dynamically change the list of options of the combobox. For example when the option list depends on another value.
> To listen to the 'select' event, you need to bind a callback to the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` virtual event (see the Bindings tab for the mycbox combobox in the example).

you can implement the callback method (which was suggested by GitHub Copilot) into your OOP approach like follows:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # inherit from Tk instead of root (optional but root is now self)
        self.title("GUI")
        self.geometry("300x300")

        self.frm = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frm.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        ttk.Label(self.frm, text="Dropdown1:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.drpDwn1 = ttk.Combobox(self.frm, values=["A", "B"])
        self.drpDwn1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.drpDwn1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.reset_flavor)  # create a callback for the selection

        ttk.Label(self.frm, text="Dropdown2:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.drpDwn2 = ttk.Combobox(self.frm, values=[""])
        self.drpDwn2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")

    def reset_flavor(self, event):  # add event since it is passed down from the bind
        value = ["A1", "A2"] if self.drpDwn1.get() == "A" else ["B1", "B2"]
        self.drpDwn2.configure(values=value)
        self.drpDwn2.set("")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gui().mainloop()  # never call mainloop() inside __init__!
```